# Extending 1D window functions to 3D (or higher)

Tags: window-functions, 3d, linear-algebra

(cross post of SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27345861/extending-1d-function-across-3-dimensions-for-data-windowing )

For the sake of image (volume) registration, I'd like to apply a windowing function to input data, such that the non-periodic image boundaries do not cause streaking in the FFT. I'm using the example from here for 2D data:

http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2008-July/036112.html

```
h = scipy.signal.hamming(n)
ham2d = sqrt(outer(h,h))
```

Is this extensible to 3D or even N-D?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a [window function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function) just applies a weighting function to your data.

For N-D data you can view the window function as a combination of N 1-D windows which are all orthogonal to each other.

As the weights of the 1-D windows to not depend on the other dimensions you can either apply each separately or combine them to get a single N-D window.

e.g. for 3D (in matlab, it should be simple enough to translate to python)

```
hammx=hamming(L); %1D window
hammy=hamx';
hamz=permute(hamx, [3, 2, 1]);
ham2=ones(L);
ham3=ones(L, L, L);
for i=1:100               % there is probably a much better way to compute this
ham2(i, :)=hamx(i).*hamy;
for j=1:100
ham3(i, j, :)=ham2(i, j).*hamz;
end
end
```

Comment: I have posted my Python code solution on Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27345861/extending-1d-function-across-3-dimensions-for-data-windowing  Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: I down voted because it only discussed the trivial extension. There are more ways of going from 1d to 2d

Answer (score 2):

this question is old, but  I needed same function.

I wrote a function that receive one-dimensional window as parameter and transformed into a cube window

```
function [win] = window3D(w)

    L = size(w,1);
    m1 = w(:)*w(:).';
    win1 = repmat(m1, [1 1 L]);
    m2 = w(:)*ones(1,L);
    win2 = repmat(m2, [1 1 L]);
    win2 = permute(win2, [3, 2, 1]);
    win = win1.*win2;
end
```

Comment: This answer works wonderfully well

Answer (score 1):

For those who would like a Python version of Angel's answer, here it is:

```
import numpy as np

def window3D(w):
    # Convert a 1D filtering kernel to 3D
    # eg, window3D(numpy.hanning(5))
    L=w.shape[0]
    m1=np.outer(np.ravel(w), np.ravel(w))
    win1=np.tile(m1,np.hstack([L,1,1]))
    m2=np.outer(np.ravel(w),np.ones([1,L]))
    win2=np.tile(m2,np.hstack([L,1,1]))
    win2=np.transpose(win2,np.hstack([1,2,0]))
    win=np.multiply(win1,win2)
    return win
```

Answer (score 0):

Separable extensions are trivial: you can obtain an n-D window with a product of 1-D windows, and they can be different to account for image or volume anisotropy, etc. Fast to compute (separability), but has drawbacks: low-rank, and sometimes a very fast decay: the decays in each dimension are multiplied.

Non-separable extensions can be interesting. If you have a formula for a 1-D discrete window, you can extend it by changing the 1-D center minus lag $|c-l|$ by a more generic norm/quasi-norm in n-D: $||c(x,y,z)-l(x,y,z)||$. The shape of the norm will drive the isotropy, decay, etc.

And you can start from a continuous formula, and discretize and normalize it properly.